# C++ multiple definition errors in 3-way header include

Tags: c++, header, include, g++

I have 3 header files defining objects:

Point3d.h

```
#ifndef POINT3D_H
#define POINT3D_H

class Ray3d;
class Vector3d;
#include "Ray3d.h"
#include "Vector3d.h"


class Point3d {
     ...
};
#endif
```

Vector3d.h

```
#ifndef VECTOR3D_H
#define VECTOR3D_H


class Point3d;
class Ray3d;

#include "Ray3d.h"
#include "Point3d.h"


class Vector3d {
    ...

};

#endif
```

and Ray3d.h

```
#ifndef RAY3D_H
#define RAY3D_H


class Point3d;
class Vector3d;

#include "Point3d.h"
#include "Vector3d.h"


class Ray3d {
    ...

};

#endif
```

I won't include the .cpp files, but all the functions are defined there.

And then I have this class:
Transform.h

```
#ifndef TRANSFORM_H
#define TRANSFORM_H

#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include "../../geometry/Ray3d.cpp"
#include "../../geometry/Point3d.cpp"
#include "../../geometry/Vector3d.cpp"


using Eigen::MatrixXd;


class Transform {
    ...
};
#endif
```

AND FINALLY I have this subclass:
Translation.h

```
#ifndef TRANSLATION_H
#define TRANSLATION_H

//#include <Eigen/Dense>

#include "Transform.h"


//#include "../../geometry/Point3d.cpp"
//#include "../../geometry/Vector3d.cpp"
//#include "../../geometry/Ray3d.cpp"

using Eigen::MatrixXd;


class Translation : public Transform {
    ...
};
#endif
```

The problem is when I try to compile Translation.cpp:

```
g++ Transform.cpp Translation.cpp
```

I get a multiple definition of function error for every method in Ray3d, Point3d, and Vector3d.  What can I do do avoid this?  Should I be including less?  Is my g++ command wrong?  Thanks!

I'm also aware that I'm doing both forward declaration and includes in the first 3 headers, but that was the only way I could get those to compile.  Part of the problem maybe?

Comment: Only include in a file what you _need_ for that file.  The definition of the `point` class doesn't need to know what a `Ray3d` or `Vector3d` are.  Yes, including and declaring those are related to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include the cpp files in transform.h

Answer (score 0):

> *"but that was the only way I could get those to compile. Part of the problem maybe?"*

You compile and link `.cpp` files separately, instead of including them (i.e. being seen from the preprocessor).

Your compiler command line should look rather like

```
g++ ../../geometry/Ray3d.cpp 
    ../../geometry/Point3d.cpp
    ../../geometry/Vector3d.cpp 
    Transform.cpp Translation.cpp
    -o MyExecutable
```